# slightly change question after the answers given weren't what the asker wanted

Tags: discussion

The op asked a question ([this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33343/ultimate-puzzling-challenge-puzzle-a1/33344?noredirect=1#comment100296_33344)) where his original question was:

> two capital cities bordering each other, Find the distance to the smallest country.

2 people responded with the same (and obviously correct) answer. however those answers were not what the OP wanted so he has (ever so slightly) changed the question (emphasis on change).

> Two capital cities bordering each other **far south**, Find the distance to the smallest country **anywhere**.

Is he allowed to change the question (even though it more or less stays the same) in the hope of getting the answer he was expecting? Or would the better thing to do is accept 1 of the answers and then create a new post with a better formatted question? What is the correct way to do?

Comment: This sort of thing generally *is* frowned upon, but we should also be careful to note that this is potentially an issue with any conceivable question—it's not possible to cover all potential loopholes or contradictions, nor is it reasonable to expect anyone to foresee all such ahead of time. As such, it's less about what's "allowed" and more about us giving guidance and showing patience.

Comment: That said, if someone is *egregiously* changing their question, this is what downvotes are for, since we can't really force anybody to choose an answer or create a new question.

Comment: IMO editing the question to clarify is better than the alternative.